# iOS6 apple maps - is it possible to get a list of visible streets and their accompanying latitude and longitude

Tags: ios6, geolocation, maps

I don't even know if this is possible.  When looking at Apple maps at a certain zoom level, certain streets are visible.  Is it possible to get a list of all the visible streets, and latitude and longitude of all the direction changes? I guess if one gets a starting point of the street and the ending point of the street (addresses), I suppose one could get a "route" of geo locations and be able to draw a polyline, and I guess that would be one way of getting a list of geo locations.  However, I am at a loss as to how does one get a list of all the visible streets..  Ideally I would like to be able to eventually figure out programmatically the geo location of street intersections.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That street vectors you cannot get via an api.
Some countries have published their street data. Then you find them in `OpenStreetMap`
The data Apple uses are from TomTom which bought TeleAtlas. You can get test data from them, but for a real project it really gets expensive, so that makes in nost cass no sense for an app. 
The only app that uses that data is from TomTom itself.